# Simple guest list database design

Tags: database, database-design

A question for DB designers:

In a guest list for a party, we will have Hosts (those who organize and attend the party) and Guests (those who are just attending the party).

There are two types of Guests:

1. Guest with invitation card: those receiving the invitation card physically at their homes, and
2. Guests without invitation card: those who need to be accompanied with a Guest that holds an invitation card, in order to enter the party.

It's understood that it's necessary to register the addresses of the first type of Guests, as it's necessary to know where to drop the invitation card.
Also, for every Guest, it's required to know the Host or Guest ID from who is inviting them.

The question is:
How many tables should I create?
A single one, with all the audience in it?
Two tables: one for Hosts, one for Guests?
Three tables: one for Hosts, one for Guests with invitation card, and another one for Guests without invitation card?

The advantage I see in the third solution (three tables) is that I avoid leaving blank the field "address" for the Guests without invitation card, and I'm able to register the ID of the Guest with invitation card that is going to take them.

I'd be glad to read the opinions and ideas from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Five tables, at least.

```
Host
----
Host ID
Host Name
...

Invited Guest
-------------
Invited Guest ID
Invited Guest Name
Invited Guest Address
...

Guest
-----
Guest ID
Guest Name
...

Party
-----
Party ID
Host ID
Party Time stamp
Party Address
...

Party Guest
-----------
Party Guest ID
Party ID
Invited Guest ID
Guest ID
...
```

I always define the primary (clustering) key of the table as an auto incrementing integer or long.

The foreign keys should be obvious by the names.  The Guest ID foreign key in the Party Guest table is a nullable foreign key.  An invited guest can invite a guest, but doesn't have to.

Two more tables would help minimize the amount of duplication in the five tables above.

```
Name
----
Name ID
Name

Address
-------
Address ID
Address
```

Since guests for one party are likely to be hosts for another party, these tables minimize the data duplication.

You just replace every name column with the Name ID, and every address column with the Address ID.

Answer (score 0):

There's always more then one solution to a problem (ok, well, most of the time there is). So you can do this in many ways, with one table, two, or three. You could put all of them in one table, setting a flag of host, invited guest and brought guest, and a field 'invited by' that points to the id of the one who he was invited by (a host, or an invited guest in).
You could use two tables, one for hosts, one for guests. This way you can refer the 'brought' guests to the invited guests, and all guests to their corresponding hosts. It also enables you to capture the addresses of the brought guests, which is never a bad idea.
You could use three tables: hosts, guests, guests2hosts. Same as above, but a many-to-many relationship between hosts and guests (in the guests2hosts table), which enables you to have guests that are invited to multiple parties.
and I guess if you think about it even further, you could come up with even more possible DB-layouts.
Creating your DB is something that you need to think about very carefully, about the current needs, and about the possible future needs. Many systems work well now, but can never be expanded because of crappy databasedesign.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I know that the number of tables could be any, but I'm looking for the rigth number of tables that would allow me to link Hosts with Guests, and Guests with 'brougth' Guests. Your idea about using tables holding many-to-many relationships would be great for multiple parties.

Answer (score 0):

ok here is a more generic alternative:

```
person
-----------
person_id
name

event
-----------
event_id
name
event_begin_datetime
event_end_datetime

person_event
--------------
person_id
event_id
role_code <-- use this to indicate which type of guest or host
invitation_mailed <-- helpful flag which may otherwise be derivable based on role

address
--------------
address_id
other address fields

person_address
-------------
person_id
address_id

event_address
--------------
event_id 
address_id
```